# Uncaught Error: No module: angularTypeahead

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

Angular typeahead throws me Uncaught Error: No module: angularTypeahead. I am using angular typeahead at my project. 
I have added script to my index.html, like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/app.js"></script>
```

index.html:

```
<div class="row center" ng-app="angularTypeahead">
    <div style="margin-top:0px;" class="col l12 s12 m12" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <h4 class="header col s12 light">NAME
        <input name="location" id="location" type="text"
               placeholder="Change Location" ng-model="selected"
               typeahead="area for area in areas| filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
               class="form-control">
    </h4>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red">
        <i class="material-icons left"></i>Change Location</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('angularTypeahead',['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope) {
        var areas = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas",
                     "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware",
                     "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois",
                     "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana",
                     "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan",
                     "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana",
                     "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey",
                     "New Mexico", "New York", "North Dakota", "North Carolina",
                     "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania",
                     "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota",
                     "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia",
                     "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];

        $scope.selected = undefined;

        $scope.areas = areas;

    });
});
```

I have found lots of discussion regarding the issue but nothing changes the error. I hope someone will help on this issue. 
Thanks!..

Comment: Probably there is missing `ng-view`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: Have you installed the directive? I only see the template file....

Comment: Doesn't require directive nor ng-view in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should invoke the function with a parenthesis. `(function(){ ... })()`

Or just don't wrap in function.

```
var app = angular.module();
app.controller();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js your function is supposed to be self-executed or so called Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). In order to accomplish this you need to change the very last line:

```
})();
```

More information on IIFE:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression